# Get sum of nested Collection failed Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested, relationship

I need the sum of nested relationship collection. When I try this code, the field could not be found.

```
  return Offer::where("id", $offer_id)
    ->with(['rooms.products' => function($sql) use ($product_id) {
        $sql->where('product_id', $product_id);
    }]
    )->sum("value");
```

Value field exists in rooms.products table.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you show the result of that query using `get`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the `sum()` method will look for the `value` column in the `offers` table, while you need the value in the `products` table. Try this approach:

```
return Product::where('product_id', $product_id)
    ->whereHas('room.offer', function($sql) use ($offer_id) {
        $sql->where("id", $offer_id)
    })->sum("value");
```

Comment: this works fine but in the products table there are several thousands of entries with the same product id. It is not the most elegant solution I think. thank you !